# .stop(), and .pause() don't work where .play() does work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html5-audio

On a .js page in a Visual Studio express ASP.NET solution
why does

```
window.onload() {
document.getElementById('ambience').play(); 
}
```

work(and it does!), but why does

```
window.onload() {
document.getElementById('ambience').play(); 
document.getElementById('ambience').stop(); 
}
```

NOT stop the music? `.pause();` doesn't pause the music either
I also tried:

It does play the music. And I have tried:

```
window.onload =  function() {

    var snd = document.getElementById('ambience').play();
    var clickmeButton = document.getElementById('playJackpot');
    clickmeButton.onclick = playSound;
}

function playSound() {
    document.getElementById('ambience').stop();
}
```

what is the equivalent of .stop() or .pause() if those are not applicable? what set of commands 
should I be working with in visual studio in order to get sound to play based on a conditional and then definitively shut off or stop after it has played once, and only once ? The background to this is that I have the play button in a timer control, so that it can operate other features, but each timer tick (and that needs to be set at a fraction of a second) kicks off the play again, so that the sound comes out staccato, because it is starting with every 'tick' of the timer. So, I need to play it, then immediately shut off the sound's ability to play, that is until somebody hits the play button again.

Comment: you're telling it to play and stop milliseconds apart from each other, it probably can't stop because it hasn't started yet.

Comment: in addition, `stop()` doesn't seem to be a valid method http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: don't put code in comments, update your question with more info if more info is needed to convey your problem

Comment: Is question in acceptable format?